# Python : populate a new column with an if/else statement

Tags: python

I have a csv file composed of three column.

My goal is to add a fourth column and populate it with a statement based on my columns n°2 and n°3.

Here is the beginning of my code :

```
import csv, sys, locale, operator

abord = "/home/julien/csv/ABORD.csv"
file1 = open (abord, 'rb')
reader1 = csv.reader (file1, delimiter = ';', quotechar=' ')

next(reader1) 
for row1 in reader1:
    ID = row1 [0]
    LARG_1 = row1 [1]
    LARG_2 = row1 [2]
```

And I want to make things like that :

```
if LARG_1 > 10 and LARG_2 <20:
    print "result OK" in a fourth column "CONTROL"
else:
    print "result fail" in the fourth column "CONTROL"

then save the csv, nom composed of 4 columns
```

Do you know how I could do it ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write to another file (using a `csv.Writer`)

```
sourcepath = "/home/julien/csv/ABORD.csv"
destpath =  "/home/julien/csv/ABORD-fixed.csv"

with open(sourcepath, "rb") as source, open(destpath, "wb") as dest:
    # XXX are you sure you want this as quotechar ???
    reader = csv.reader(source, delimiter = ';', quotechar=' ')
    writer = csv.writer(dest,  delimiter = ';', quotechar=' ')

    # first copy the (augmented) headers
    headers = reader.next()
    headers.append("CONTROL")
    writer.writerow(headers)

    # then let's loop on the content
    for rownum, row in enumerate(reader):
        # we need to convert data to int             
        # adding proper error handling here might help...
        # status = "result OK" if (int(row[1]) > 10 and int(row[2]) < 20) else "result fail"
        try:
            l1 = int(row[1])
            l2 = int(row[2])
        except (TypeError, ValueError), e:
            err = "non integer value for l1 and or l2 in row %s line %s - got : %s" % (
                rownum, reader.linenum, row
                )
            print >> sys.stderr, err
            result = "invalid values"
        else:
            if l1 > 10 and l2 < 20:
                result = "result OK"
            elif rownum == 42: # stupid value for if/elif/else exemple
                result = "what's the question ?"
            else:
                result = "result fail"

        row.append(result)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If needed you can then delete the source file and rename the new one.

Comment: Great, thank you !! And if I want to make an if/ifelse/else condition, how could you do ? Thanks again !

Comment: @Julien: basic branching is fully documented you know - maybe you should read the FineManual(tm) <g>  (but see the edited code - and feel free to accept my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno ! I just had to change the row.append(status) to row.append(result) to make it work. Thank you again.

Comment: @Julien : sorry for the typo (fixed in the snippet). You may want to mark the answer as accepted ;)