# Case/IfElse Statement in Python from CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file (`original.csv`) with a unique ID column (`uid`) and columns that I want to evaluate and then create a new file (`result.csv`) with the unmodified `uid` and create new columns based on the evaluation.

My original file looks like this:

```
uid,var01,var02,var03,var04,var05
1,2,3,2,3,1
2,2,2,2,2,1
3,,2,2,1,1
4,2,2,2,1,1
5,1,2,2,1,2
6,3,,2,3,2
7,3,,1,1,1
8,2,3,1,,3
9,3,1,,3,
10,,3,2,3,3
```

I want to do an evaluation that is the same logic as this (written in SQL): `case when var01 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as var01_new, case when var02 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as var02_new, ...`

The result would look like this:

```
uid,var01_new,var02_new,var03_new,var04_new,var05_new
1,0,0,0,0,1
2,0,0,0,0,1
3,0,0,0,1,1
4,0,0,0,1,1
5,1,0,0,1,0
6,0,0,0,0,0
7,0,0,1,1,1
8,0,0,1,0,0
9,0,1,0,0,0
10,0,0,0,0,0
```

Given the size of the actual file (~20M rows, 50+ columns) I want to keep the solution in base `Python` as opposed to memory-limited packages like `Pandas` and `Numpy`. I tried [modifying this S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397019/python-populate-a-new-column-with-an-if-else-statement) but I couldn't get it to work for my use case.

I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
>>> import csv
>>> 
>>> sourcepath = "/Users/me/python_case_statement.csv"
>>> destpath =  "/Users/me/python_case_statement_flat.csv"
>>> 
>>> with open(sourcepath, "rb") as source, open(destpath, "wb") as dest:
...     reader = csv.reader(source, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
...     writer = csv.writer(dest,  delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
...     headers = reader.next()
...     writer.writerow(headers)
...     for rownum, row in enumerate(reader):
...         'uid' = 'uid'
...         if 'var01' == 1:
...             'var01_new' == 1
...         else:
...             'var01_new' == 0
...         row.append(result)
...         writer.writerow(row)
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 7
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
>>>
```

Comment: WHat's your question, then? What happened when you modified the SO question? Which errors did you find?

Comment: What do you mean "keep the solution in base python as opposed to memory-limited packages"? In any event, this seems like a relatively straight-forward thing to do, especially given the qustion you've linked to. What have you tried exactly?

Comment: Ok, your syntax error seems pretty self explanatory... perhaps you should start with a basic Python tutorial?

Comment: Apologies @juanpa.arrivillaga and Alfabravo and for not posting my attempt at it.

Comment: Are you trying to assign `'uid' = 'uid'` ? The same for `'var01_new' == 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Python is not a purely declarative language like SQL, it is procedural so you have to describe the control flow, although it has many declarative constructs. So,

```
>>> s = """uid,var01,var02,var03,var04,var05
... 1,2,3,2,3,1
... 2,2,2,2,2,1
... 3,,2,2,1,1
... 4,2,2,2,1,1
... 5,1,2,2,1,2
... 6,3,,2,3,2
... 7,3,,1,1,1
... 8,2,3,1,,3
... 9,3,1,,3,
... 10,,3,2,3,3"""
>>> reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(s))
>>> result = io.StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(result)
```

The above just lets us pretend we are working with a file by using a stream (`io.StringIO`). But you would do this how you already have done it using your with-statement. Now, the crux of your problem:

```
>>> header = next(reader)
>>> writer.writerow(["{}_new".format(v) for v in header])
59
>>> for row in reader:
...     new_row = [row[0]] # uid the same
...     new_row.extend(1 if c == '1' else 0 for c in row[1:])
...     writer.writerow(new_row)
...
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
14
>>> print(result.getvalue())
uid_new,var01_new,var02_new,var03_new,var04_new,var05_new
1,0,0,0,0,1
2,0,0,0,0,1
3,0,0,0,1,1
4,0,0,0,1,1
5,1,0,0,1,0
6,0,0,0,0,0
7,0,0,1,1,1
8,0,0,1,0,0
9,0,1,0,0,0
10,0,0,0,0,0

>>>
```

I've used comprehension constructs and conditional expressions, which allow for nicer, more declarative ways to transform data. But you could do the same thing without them, using `if-else` statements and building up your rows:

```
>>> result = io.StringIO()
>>> reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(s))
>>> writer = csv.writer(result)
>>> header = next(reader)
>>> new_header = []
>>> for s in header:
...     new_header.append("{}_new".format(s))
...
>>> writer.writerow(new_header)
59
>>> for row in reader:
...     new_row = []
...     for c in row:
...         if c == '1':
...             new_row.append(1)
...         else:
...             new_row.append(0)
...     writer.writerow(new_row)
...
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
>>> print(result.getvalue())
uid_new,var01_new,var02_new,var03_new,var04_new,var05_new
1,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,1,1
0,0,0,0,1,1
0,1,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1
0,0,0,1,0,0
0,0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're trying to assign `'uid' = 'uid'` and `'var01_new' == 0` which is incorrect and your code will throw an exception `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`.

Otherwise, you can asnwer to your question, too, without using `csv` module, like this example:

I'm assuming your input file is called `id_input.csv` and your output file is called `new.csv`:

```
data = ([k.strip(',')] for k in open("id_input.csv", 'r'))

condition = True

with open("new.csv", 'a') as f:
    for k in data:
        if condition:
            f.write("uid,var01_new,var02_new,var03_new,var04_new,var05_new\n")
            condition = False
        else:
            dd = k[0].split(",")
            f.write(dd[0] + ',' + ",".join(j if j == '1' else '0'  for j in dd[1:]) + '\n')
```

So within the code above and with this input:

```
uid,var01,var02,var03,var04,var05
1,2,3,2,3,1
2,2,2,2,2,1
3,,2,2,1,1
4,2,2,2,1,1
5,1,2,2,1,2
6,3,,2,3,2
7,3,,1,1,1
8,2,3,1,,3
9,3,1,,3,
10,,3,2,3,3
```

The output file `new.csv` will have this data:

```
uid,var01_new,var02_new,var03_new,var04_new,var05_new
1,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0
3,0,0,0,1,0
4,0,0,0,1,0
5,1,0,0,1,0
6,0,0,0,0,0
7,0,0,1,1,0
8,0,0,1,0,0
9,0,1,0,0,0
10,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks Chiheb, that will work for a similar use case.

Comment: Thanks and Welcome :-)