# Python: Populate new df column based on if statement condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying something new. I want to populate a new df column based on some conditions affecting another column with values.

I have a data frame with two columns (ID,Retailer). I want to populate the Retailer column based on the ids in the ID column. I know how to do this in SQL, using a CASE statement, but how can I go about it in python?

I've had look at this example but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

[Python : populate a new column with an if/else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397019/python-populate-a-new-column-with-an-if-else-statement)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID':['112','5898','32','9985','23','577','17','200','156']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Retailer']=''

if df['ID'] in (112,32):
    df['Retailer']='Webmania'
elif df['ID'] in (5898):
    df['Retailer']='DataHub'
elif df['ID'] in (9985):
    df['Retailer']='TorrentJunkie'
elif df['ID'] in (23):
    df['Retailer']='Apptronix'
else: df['Retailer']='Other'


print(df)
```

The output I'm expecting to see would be something along these lines:

```
     ID Retailer
0   112 Webmania
1  5898 DataHub
2    32 Webmania
3  9985 TorrentJunkie
4    23 Apptronix
5   577 Other
6    17 Other
7   200 Other
8   156 Other
```

Comment: In general be careful that '112' (a text string) is different from 112 (a number), so when checking if two values are equal, you'll get no match if you mix your types.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MrFelix. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and for test multiple values use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), also if need test strings like in sample data change numbers to numeric like `112` to `'112'`:

```
m1 = df['ID'].isin(['112','32'])
m2 =  df['ID'] == '5898'
m3 =  df['ID'] == '9985'
m4 =  df['ID'] == '23'
vals = ['Webmania', 'DataHub', 'TorrentJunkie', 'Apptronix']
masks = [m1, m2, m3, m4]

df['Retailer'] = np.select(masks, vals, default='Other')
print(df)

     ID       Retailer
0   112       Webmania
1  5898        DataHub
2    32       Webmania
3  9985  TorrentJunkie
4    23      Apptronix
5   577          Other
6    17          Other
7   200          Other
8   156          Other
```

If many catagories also is possible use your solution with custom function:

```
def get_data(x):
    if x in ('112','32'):
        return 'Webmania'
    elif x == '5898':
        return 'DataHub'
    elif x == '9985':
        return 'TorrentJunkie'
    elif x == '23':
        return 'Apptronix'
    else: return 'Other'


df['Retailer'] =  df['ID'].apply(get_data)
print (df)
     ID       Retailer
0   112       Webmania
1  5898        DataHub
2    32       Webmania
3  9985  TorrentJunkie
4    23      Apptronix
5   577          Other
6    17          Other
7   200          Other
8   156          Other
```

Or use `map` by dictionary, if no match get `NaN`, so added `fillna`:

```
d = {'112': 'Webmania','32':'Webmania',
    '5898':'DataHub',
    '9985':'TorrentJunkie',
    '23':'Apptronix'}

df['Retailer'] =  df['ID'].map(d).fillna('Other')
```